# Why does \makesavenoteenv not work with align?

Tags: footnotes, align

Putting

```
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{align}
```

into the preamble results in the following error:

```
 \end{align*}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

In contrast using `\makesavenoteenv` with other environments e.g. `eqnarray` works.

Using

```
\savenotes
\begin{align}
...
\end{align}
\spewnotes
```

works as expected.

Comment: Maybe it's because one has to be in math mode to invoke `eqnarray`, but one has NOT to be in math mode to invoke `align`. (It's just a thought...)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `align` environment works differently from `minipage` and other environments, because it saves its contents for doing several passes over the material, in order to measure the various parts. This makes it incompatible with `footnote` that, on the other hand, is a very old and unmantained package. Do you really need footnotes in a math alignment?

Comment: 1) Everywhere one is asked to use align instead of eqnarray. But if it is impossible to use it with footnotes - no way

Comment: 2) As using `\savenotes` and `spewnotes` in the document works it should be possible to redefine `align` in the preabmle. I tried it but ran into the same trouble as the `\makesavenoteenv` command using `\renewenvironment{align}` or even `\newenvironment{align}`. `\NewEnviron` from the `environ`-package does the job but `\RenewEnviron` failed again.